# What's wrong with this mysql query in PHP?

Tags: mysql

If I echo it out, i get this:

INSERT INTO stockk (company, indications, ticker, mkt_cap, price, change) VALUES ('Pfizer Inc.', 'protein replace therapies / blood diseases / etc', 'PFE', '178.6B', '23.85', '-0.38%')

here is the code:

```
$quer1 = "INSERT INTO stockk (company, indications, ticker, mkt_cap, price, change) VALUES ('".addslashes($value['fullname'])."', '".addslashes($value['indic'])."', '".addslashes($value['symbol'])."', '".addslashes($mkt)."', '".addslashes($round)."', '".addslashes($value['PercentChange'])."')";
```

It is throwing a mysql syntax error....

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''change') VALUES ('Pfizer Inc.', 'protein replace therapies / blood diseases / e' at line 1

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Try using `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of addslashes.

Comment: what are the data types you are using for each table fields?

Comment: Is it barking about the replace in `indications` maybe?

Comment: +1. Use the backtick character to enclose identifiers. (On my keyboard, it's the leftmost key, next to the "1" key. (Normal quotes don't "work" around identifiers i.e. table names and column names) in SQL statements. The backticks are REQUIRED whenever an identifier contains special characters or the identifier matches a reserved word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `change` is a reserved word in MySQL - you are using it in your columns list. If you wrap it in SQL quotes, the syntax error goes away.

```
INSERT INTO stockk (company, indications, ticker, mkt_cap, price, `change`) VALUES [...]
```

Comment: @A_funs `did not work` is not a problem description.  Post the new error.

Comment: It works on my system. If I issue your original query, I get your syntax error. When I wrap `change` in quotes, I get `Table does not exist` - this shows me, it should at least fix *this* error. Did the error message change? Maybe there are some other errors?

Comment: For some reason wrapping it in quotes did not work, I changed the name of the column, and that did it

Comment: I used the type of quotes listed in the answer

Comment: Then it would have worked with them. Note that they are `\``, not `'` (there's a difference).